# How to insert rows which optionally have parent rows in the same table at once

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.2

Given is the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE public.parenttest (
  id      bigserial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  mydata  varchar(30),
  parent  bigint
  ) WITH (
    OIDS = FALSE
);
```

I'd like to insert a bunch of rows. Some of these rows should take  the sequence-generated `id` of a row inserted before as value for the column `parent`.

For example:

```
INSERT INTO parenttest (mydata,parent) VALUES ('rootnode',null); 
INSERT INTO parenttest (mydata,parent) VALUES ('child1', /*id of rootnode*/); 
INSERT INTO parenttest (mydata,parent) VALUES ('child2', /*id of rootnode*/); 
INSERT INTO parenttest (mydata,parent) VALUES ('child2.1', /*id of child 2*/);
INSERT INTO parenttest (mydata.parent) VALUES ('child2.2', /*id of child 2*/);
```

...should result in the following datasets (id, mydata,parent)

```
1,'rootnode',null
2,'child1',1
3,'child2',1
4,'child2.1',3
5,'child2.2',3
```

UNTIL `child2.2`, everything is fine when i'm using

```
SELECT currval('parenttest_id_seq');
```

to get the parent's `id` but then i'm getting the id of `child2.2`, of course.

It's important to me that i can do all necessary stuff with as few client-side requests as possible - and i'd like to do all id generation on the server-side.

Comment: I did not understand your question. You can add the parent and save its ID, and insert the others child/sub_child. This is what you want ?

Comment: I've added the expected results to the post. I hope that this is understandable now.

Comment: Since `parent` can be `null`, would it be acceptable to insert all of the rows first, and then perform an `UPDATE` that retrieves the appropriate IDs based on the `mydata` values? (I.e. the rows would briefly exist with `null` `parent`)

Comment: Personally, I'd either manage the identity column myself, or I'd create a `TEMPORARY` table, insert the data, then use a server-side `DO` block or a function to merge it into the main table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I'd do it, if it's acceptable for the rows to briefly have a `NULL` parent:

```
INSERT INTO parenttest (mydata) VALUES
('rootnode'), 
('child1'),
('child2'), 
('child2.1'),
('child2.2');

UPDATE parenttest SET parent = (select id from parenttest pt where
(pt.mydata = 'rootnode' and parenttest.mydata in ('child1','child2')) or
(pt.mydata = 'child2' and parenttest.mydata in ('child2.1','child2.2')))
WHERE
  mydata in ('child1',
             'child2', 
             'child2.1',
             'child2.2');
```

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/15c1e/1)

Comment: For the most cases, i guess that could be a possible solution - thanks for that already. Unfortunately, it's not assured that the values will be unique.

Comment: @TheJeed - then you need to carefully consider what your data actually represents. Auto-generated ids are all well and good, but if you don't also have a *natural* key that allows you to uniquely identify rows, then you've got no real way to avoid ending up with duplicate data.

Comment: If I had to go with this approach, I would first create a temp table with `VALUES (parent, child), (parent, child)` etc. and then `UPDATE parenttest SET parent=(SELECT id FROM temp_table WHERE temp_table.parent

Answer (score 1):

You could do something as ugly as:

```
INSERT INTO parenttest (mydata,parent) VALUES ('rootnode',null); 
INSERT INTO parenttest (mydata,parent) SELECT 'child1', id FROM parenttest WHERE mydata='rootnode';
INSERT INTO parenttest (mydata,parent) SELECT 'child2', id FROM parenttest WHERE mydata='rootnode';
INSERT INTO parenttest (mydata,parent) SELECT 'child2.1', id FROM parenttest WHERE mydata='child2';
INSERT INTO parenttest (mydata.parent) SELECT 'child2.2', id FROM parenttest WHERE mydata='child2';
```

I think the right thing to do here is go with client-side, retrieving the id of 'rootnode' after inserting it, and then sending the following two statements with its id explicitly in the INSERT statement.

Answer (score 0):

After some experiments, i've found one solution using an anonymous PL/PgSQL code block:

```
DO $$DECLARE
  parentid bigint;
BEGIN  
  INSERT INTO parenttest (mydata) VALUES ('rootnode');  
  parentid:=currval('parenttest_id_seq');  
  INSERT INTO parenttest (mydata,parent) VALUES ('child 1',parentid);
  INSERT INTO parenttest (mydata,parent) VALUES ('child 2',parentid);
  parentid:=currval('parenttest_id_seq');
  INSERT INTO parenttest (mydata,parent) VALUES ('child 2.1',parentid),('child 2.2',parentid);
END$$;
```

It's possible to use it within a single request from the client and i don't have to generate anything at the client-side, so this may be one possible solution for my problem.

Edit:
It can be expressed shorter like this:

```
DO $$DECLARE
  parentid bigint;
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO parenttest (mydata) VALUES ('Flat') RETURNING id INTO parentid;
  INSERT INTO parenttest (mydata, parent) VALUES ('Subflat 1', parentid);
  INSERT INTO parenttest (mydata, parent) VALUES ('Subflat 2', parentid)RETURNING id INTO parentid;
  INSERT INTO parenttest (mydata, parent) VALUES ('Subflat 2.1', parentid), ('Subflat 2.2', parentid);
END$$;
```